# Including dependencies using @wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I would like to add include additional script handles to the dependencies in `assets.php` using [@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin).

An example for this would be a script that extends `masonry` which is a script that is [included and registered by WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-and-js-libraries-included-and-registered-by-wordpress).

Comment: this is usually documented as a part of WP Scripts usage rather than that particular package

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow 

Comment: people rarely use that package you linked to directly. Instead they use the WP Scripts package, which uses the extraction plugin as a dependency. If you look for documentation to do this in the extraction package, you won't find it because it's documented on the WP Scripts package in the handbook

Comment: Also what you're wanting to do is already documented on the page you linked to via requestToExternal and requestToHandle, you should be able to rename my module to `masonry` from the 2 examples.

Comment: Thanks, yea, I am using the extraction package as part of `@wordpress/scripts`. So you are saying that something like this should work: https://gist.github.com/grappler/d1b226565d8efb24cbadefe2712f3d15
What I am unsure about is how the import in my file should be and if `masonry` needs to be part of the `package.json`

Comment: What the import looks like would depend on the masonry object that you get if you enqueue masonry normally. And no it doesn't need to be a part of the package file. In essence you're mapping ` package import statement into a variable assignment. `import { banana } from '@wordpress/element';` gets turned into `banana = window.wp.element.banana;`. `requestToExternal` tells webpack what the `window.wp.element` part is and to trust that it'll be there because we enqueued it. `requestToHandle` tells webpack what the handle to enqueue is or the PHP file it generates